# Copy function is not working on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I made a function in JS to copy a text to clipboard. I added the button to an website. On desktop is working (Chrome, Mozilla etc), but on Android Chrome is not working.

What i need to add to make it work on Android Chrome, to copy to clipboard?

Thank you!

```
function copyCupon(cupon){
    var copyText = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(copyText);
    copyText.setAttribute("id", "copyTextId");
    copyText.setAttribute('value', cupon);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(copyText);
    alert("Cuponul " +"'"+copyText.value+"'" +" a fost copiat. Spor la cumparaturi! :)");
}
```

Comment: I suppose the error in `document.execCommand`. What the concrete "not working" do you have?

Comment: No error on Android Chrome. Just nothing happens. I click on button and try to paste but is not the value from the function calling.

Comment: I am also facing this problem did you find any solution

Comment: @MrinmoyMk nope :(

Comment: I have just done it in another way and it is working. If you are still facing this problem then please let me know, I will post the other way which I am using and it works

Comment: @MrinmoyMk I'm facing the same issue, and i'm interested in your solution that works

Comment: @allan.simon I had posted an answer for you in the question. Do upvote if it works for you as well

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me in all of the browser including Android Chrome -

```
function copyToClipboard(data){
 
   var tempItem = document.createElement('input');
   tempItem.setAttribute('type','text');
   tempItem.setAttribute('display','none');
   let content = data;
   if (data instanceof HTMLElement) {
        content = data.innerHTML;
   }
   tempItem.setAttribute('value',content);
   document.body.appendChild(tempItem);
   tempItem.select();
   document.execCommand('Copy');
   tempItem.parentElement.removeChild(tempItem);
 }
```